# mongodb returning wrong results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Inside aggregation, I want to search two fields if they contain (one or the other) a same string variable. But the search is done only on one field.

This is my code:

```
const textFilter = req.body.freeTextFilter !== '' ? `.*${req.body.freeTextFilter}*.` : '.';
```

...

```
{
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { name: { $regex: textFilter, $options: 'i' } },
        { comment: { $regex: textFilter, $options: 'i' } }
      ]
    }
  },
```

...

What am I doing wrong? The search is done only on the comment field.

The schema looks like this (there are more field):

```
const Activity = new Schema({
  name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
  },
  comment: {
    type: String
  },
},
```

If one document has the field 'name' that contains a specific text, and another one has the field 'comment' that contains the same specific text, i expect that the query return both documents.
If i search only on the 'name' field (without $or), it doesn't returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. The query works fine, the problem was somewhere else. As I wrote before, I didn't get the right results, but it was because of the paging logic that was wrong.